# Percentage of 3 different range of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, math, percentage

I have 3 numbers 113, 6, 1

Each of these number represnts a data. So I need to show the data graphically. So, the 113 will have the maximum data, then 6 will have less than that and 1 is the least.

[image]

Something like this. So if I use the percentage method, it gives me the last data of the least number as 0% and hence I am not able to show it in the image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: To represent `1 / 120`, you will need at least `120` circles (or use fractions of circles).

Comment: Consider a more quantitative chart such as a barchart.

Comment: @seandavi Or a [pie chart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U0nWi.png), because I think pies are delicious.

Answer (score 2):

Either you increase the number of balloons so that it is equal to the sum of your numbers divided the least (in this case the least is 1, so you need 113+6+1 = 120 balloons), or you "adjust" the percentages so that the minimum number of balloons you get is 1 anyway.

In this case, c = 1 means a percentage of 1/120 and you need less than one balloon. So you take 1 balloon out of your 33 and assign it to 1. Then 6+113 have to divide 32 balloons, and 6 gets 32*6/(6+113) = 1.6 balloons. You can assign to it 2 balloons and this leaves 30 for the value of 113.

Drawn percentages will then be 1/33, 2/33 and 30/33, i.e. approximately 3%, 6% and 90% instead of the "real" values of 0.83%, 5% and 94.16% that you cannot represent. Is it close enough? You have to judge.

Another possibility is to look into how to generate "mixed color" balloons, if possible at all.

Comment: Thanks.. appreciated! but it wont be 120 total all the times. The number might be in thousands too like 10000 , 4, 1. At that time how should i go about?

Comment: In the same way. You will get one balloon for 1, one balloon for 4, and the lion's share of balloons for 10000. Hey, the basic problem here is that 10000 and 1 are *waaay* not on the same scale, there can be no "exact" solution for *that*!

Comment: Use a logarithmic scale. Either use a graph or find a way to visually represent the powers, e.g. different colors or shapes represent 1, 10, 1000, 10000. So 4 of one shape/color represents 10,000 while 4 of a different one would represent 4.

Comment: @Alan, good call, but I fear that the user interface wouldn't be as clear. Unfortunately, the OP is trying to make a silk purse out of a sow's ear. If this unbalance of numbers is frequent, I'd suggest to reevaluate completely the interface, maybe really go for a pie chart (NullUserException's suggestion).

Comment: @lserni I do not disagree with you, I was just pointing out that it is **possible** to represent numbers with order of magnitude differences in a way that doesn't have 1 value with the rest nearing zero